# Preventing race conditions in Nodejs sql select - update insert

Tags: node.js, sql-server

I have a logic in Nodejs with SQL database like this:

```
let checkIfRecordAlreadyExists = await pool.query(my_query)

if checkIfRecordAlreadyExists then 
   await pool.query(`Insert in mytable`)
else
   await pool.query(`Update mytable`)
```

As you can see this is susceptible to race condition if two different requests reach the select statement at the same time.

To remove race condition, I cannot wrap this in transaction because the transaction will only lock the table when it reaches insert or update, a transaction never locks a table when running select. So even if I wrap the above SQL in transaction, if two requests get to the select clause inside the transaction at the same time we still have race condition.

Please advise how I can handle this.

Comment: Please tag only one RDBMS that you use. `MySQL <> SQL Server`

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14220/transact.htm

Comment: I was thinking this is more a logical issue with any database rather than specific database. Am I still not allowed to use both tags?

Comment: @SC1000 the link you posted just describes transaction and I already know how to use them. As I mentioned above transaction doesn't really prevent race condition in this case. It will reduce the chances of race condition but it does not solve the problem

Comment: It's allowed to tags all possible RDBMS, but when you tag only DB that you use, you will get more relevant answers.

Answer (score 0):

You could introduce a lock mechanism in your nodejs code. Using the [async-mutex](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async-mutex) library this could look something like:

```
const addRecordLock = new Mutex();

app.post('/add-record', async (req, res) => { 
    const lockRelease = await addRecordLock.acquire();
    try {
        // do the rest of your logic here
         let checkIfRecordAlreadyExists = await pool.query(my_query)
         // ...
    } catch (error) {
        // handle error
    } finally {
        // always release the lock
        lockRelease();
    }

});
```

This makes sure only one request executes the logic after the lock has been required. If other requests arrive in the meantime, they are queued and the next one will be processed as soon as the lock is released.

Comment: @jedu: any feedback?